# Multiple database corruption on SQL Server 2000 MSDE

Tags: sql-server, database

We use SQL Server 2000 MSDE for an Point Of Sale system running on about 800 cash registers. Each box has its own copy, and only the local software accesses it.

This is a newly updated platform for the cash register vendor--who shall remain nameless.

Routinely we are seeing corruption of Master, MSDB, Model and the database used by the software.

I am looking for some piece of mind here more than anything and the confidence to utter that age old response: "It's not a software problem, it's a hardware problem".

My gut tells me that with this type of corruption a hardware problem is indicated. Can anyone suggest some alternatives to check out?

**Edit**: New information on problem

It has been a while since I first posted this problem. It turns out that aggressive use of CHKDSK in a preventative fashion seems to minimize the occurrences of the problem. Also it seems I failed to mention that the registers are running the WePOS version of Windows XP. Finally I have had cases where there were also corrupted files not part of the app which were fixed with CHKDSK.

Do any of these new facts strike a chord with anyone?

Comment: Seriously... Don't install 800 copies of SQL 2000 MSDE.  I hate to think of the number of patches you must be installing as well.  Who knows what state your system is really in after all those patches.

Comment: i agree, limit your points of entry to your database

Answer (score 1):

I have a rule of thumb that for every 100 problems 90 of them are user misunderstandings (like turning off the PC), 10 are caused by software and 1 is hardware.

With so many systems to update I would be looking for things like, systems that have not been fully patched.  Users turning off PCs, and so on.  Are the PCs locking up or crashing?

If the answers to all the above questions is no, then based on the rule of thumb I would be looking towards your software, as that would be the interface (presumably) to the SQL database.

There isn't enough information here to be more helpful.

Is this software you have written?

Answer (score 0):

I know its not an "alternative" but believe it or not i have found many answers to my microsoft problems from microsoft.

You might want to submit a query at the [microsoft developer network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have gone down that path before and been mistaken. Have you been able to identify any cases of data corruption in the OS or any other files? Also, if your POS doesn't have to be up during non-business hours, try running a stress test loading data into your schema directly, and through the data layer of your app (if possible).

These may not find the problem, but there are still a number of sneaky ways for these problems to spread other than bad hardware.